# Как включить в программу другие программы?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как скопировать исполняемый файл из ресурсов программы и сохранить в произвольном месте? Есть ли альтернативы?

Comment: Есть 2 проги, но один экзешник. Как из первой проги создать экзешник второй проги? Как мне хранить эту другую прогу, как потом извлечь?

Comment: а для чего такое нужно? не проще в инсталлятор запихнуть обе и его уже распространять в виде одного файла? Или это такой хитрый способ обойти ограничения безопасности? тогда тем более странно, любой антивирь с проактивными эвристиками зарежет обе, чтоб не повадно было.

Comment: так то, из ресурсов доставать не сложнее чем любой другой бинарный ресурс. Потом сохраняешь на диск, и запускаешь отдельным процессом. Читай про работу с ресурсами. Если хорошо поискать, на MSDN даже примеров рабочих накопать можно

Comment: Нет, не проще. Вот, Unity и VS собирают экзешники, так? Только мне нужна не динамичная компиляция, а именно создания экземпляра уже готовой проги.

Comment: И? Чем это отличается от того, что делает инсталлятор? Берет готовые экземпляры, распаковывает их из своих внутренних ресурсов и размещает в указанном месте ФС. Или под готовым экземпляром вы имеете ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: Так мне нужно создавать вторую прогу не при инсталляции и совсем не один раз. Я не просто так привел Unity в пример, но в моем случае все проще, и нужно маленькие программки-интерпретаторы создавать.

Comment: ок. Продолжаем расшифровку: что значить создавать?

Comment: и перенесите уточнения в вопрос пока совсем в минуса не ушли. Тут не много у кого есть время и желание ходить-туда-не-знаю-куда. Чем подробнее опишите задачу и свои попытки как либо ее решить, тем больше вероятность получить вменяемый полезный ответ

Comment: Копировать из ресурсов, лучше ничего не могу придумать. Видимо, нужно прочесть байты и записать в нужное место?

Comment: т.е. банальное копирование файла, так? Тогда что мешает не дергать его из ресурсов, а просто копировать?

Comment: С этим пока не понятно. Желательно, чтобы файла не было в открытом виде, иначе будет риск его удаления. Значит только из ресурсов?

Comment: Чтобы не было риска удаления, можете при запуске программы проверять  заранее определенную папку на наличие нужных файлов и докачивать нужное со своего сервера. Подойдет любой хостинг. И ни кто не мешает удалить саму вашу программу если уж на то пошло

Comment: Интересно, спасибо, учту.

Comment: через ресурсы, да, сохраняете файл как бинарный ресурс, извлекаете в массив байт или MemoryStream и записываете в файл

Comment: ну и еще, если нужно скрыть файл от пользователя, пометьте его атрибутом `hidden` на уровне файловой системы. От продвинутых пользователей и выше может и не спасет, но от случайного удаления "лишнего файлика" вполне, по дефолту они не отображаются

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: если разобрались, можете написать собственный вариант решения вашей проблемы в качестве ответа

Answer (score 1):

1. Переходим в свойства (Properties) своего проекта и добавляем нужную программу в ресурсы:
   Свойства => Ресурсы => Добавить ресурс => Добавить существующий файл.
2. Программа добавилась в виде массива байтов. Осталось сохранить в нужное место:
   `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\program.exe", Properties.Resources.FileName);`